# dates comparison and logic in php

Tags: php, date, logic

I have a scenario for which i need to make some logic on the basis of dates comparison. I am kinda stuck and would really appreciate some help.

Scenario:

i have users table with these fields,

```
period, start_from, valid_to
```

the values for period could be (1 month,2 months,3 months,4 months,6 months,12 months). start_from and valid_to are dates field.

If user has selected 1 in period. That means an email should be sent to the user every month. If the user has selected 2, that means an email should be sent to the user after every two months. If 3 is selected, an email should be sent after every three months and so on.

Also if it is end of the year which is December 31st. An email should be sent to the user for past time regardless of the completion of the period.

Example: if the user's start_from date is October 2015 and has selected the period 4. An email should be sent to the user in the end of December 2015 for the month of oct, nov and dec (three months) despite the fact that 4 months are not passed. But in year 2016 a new and first email should be in the end of April as the user has selected 4 months.

I am kinda stuck with comping up the whole logic but this what i have come so far and i don't see and solution with this code. ***So better avoid the code.***

```
$currMonth = (int) date('n',$currtime);
if($currMonth<12){
    $period = (int) $PU_Result->rs['period'];
    if($period>1){
        $validFrom = (int) date('n',strtotime($PU_Result->rs['start_from']));
        $requiredMonth = $validFrom+$period;
        if($requiredMonth>12)
            $requiredMonth=12;
        if($currMonth!=$requiredMonth)
            continue;
    }

}
```

I am executing this piece of code in a loop. If the condition doesn't meet i quit the iteration otherwise i end up sending the mail.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Google "php compare date" or "mysql compare date". When you speak of fields I'm wildly guessing you use mysql. Mysql can compare dates for you.

Comment: yes i am using mysql. comparison is not the problem the logic is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check: the year of the start_from is the current year. If that is the case, then you'll need to iterate the period from that date, with the exception december.

If that's not the case: you'll start the 'loop' from january.

Pseudo:

```
if (
       (current_year == start_year)
       && (
           (start_month + period) == current_month
           || current_month == 12
       )
       || (current_month == period)
) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Special indentation added so you can see how you should build the if-statement.

This pseudo code is not entirely what you want, but it is the start of the logic you're seeking for.
For example: this would only work 1 time a year, you need to figure out how to do it every time (pro-tip: modulo operator).

Comment: Its just one line i don't know what i was thinking.... if($current_month.%$period==0) send mail; This is what i was looking for :)